# CDC ACM driver for UEFI

Tags: serial-port, usb, usbserial, cdc, uefi

I'm new to UEFI development.

So far, I have learnt about UEFI shell, build procedure and application basics.

My task is to communicate to a custom board from UEFI using uefi app through a USB cable from the PC (usb serial).

Currently, the PC is booted to UEFI shell and connected the board through serial cable and I type `devices` command, I see that the board is listed as

```
344 : CDC Abstract Control Model (CDC)
```

and

```
345: CDC ACM Data
```

Please help me to understand how I can proceed? And what works I need to do in order to detect my board as **Serial port**?

Is there any uefi driver available for this?

If I need to develop the uefi driver, please help me on what would be the starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen anyone develop a CDC driver yet, but there is a FTDI driver that could be used as a starting point.

[FtdiUsbSerialDxe on GitHub](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-platforms/tree/master/Drivers/OptionRomPkg/Bus/Usb/FtdiUsbSerialDxe)

Comment: Yes, I have seen the FtdiSerial driver... and yes, I agree that right now thats the only reference I can take... Do you have experience in modifying Ftdi driver? I want to know how complex it is to use Ftdi driver and develop a CDC driver. :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't, but the basic shape for what is needed for a UEFI driver is present.I don't know the implementation differences between FTDI's interface and the USB standard's CDC interface.

Basically, from the FTDI driver, you would get the basic framework needed.

Comment: And Tim, can you please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738862/run-a-uefi-shell-command-from-inside-uefi-application) and give your ideas? :) Asking explicitly, as there seems to be less active UEFI experts here. Thanks again! :)