# Compile UEFI Application/Driver using EDK2

Tags: shell, driver, bootloader, bios, uefi

I'm trying to build an application/driver for UEFI, which will start an UEFI Shell script.
I'm using [UDK2018](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/UDK2018#how-to-build-UDK2018) with Visual Studio 2017. I have build all tools properly, I can run SecMain which launches UEFI Shell and I have already tested following scripts:

In startup.nsh:

```
fs0:
echo -off
vol0
vol1
fs1:
vol0
vol1
```

In vol0:

```
vol > base.txt
```

In vol1:

```
vol > output.txt
comp base.txt output.txt
```

My goal is to check if there were made any changes to UEFI system. Why I prefer this to be done by application/driver? I found somewhere in documentation [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u6TM.jpg) screenshot. Maybe I'm wrong, but from Shell I can't boot operating system. I mean, automatically, because Uefi app/driver is running in UEFI Services, right? It will execute, and then pass control to some boot mechanism which launches OS.

What I have at this moment:
`C:\MyWorkspace` with EDK2 files

`C:\MyWorkspace\source` were I created a driver for IA32 architecture using UEFI Driver Wizard

`C:\Users\username\source\repos\BootCheck` with Makefile Project, with following settings: [Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoxFg.jpg) and [NMake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpSUT.jpg). Then I include a `BootCheck.c` from `C:\MyWorkspace\source`

I probably need to add some lines of code into .dec or .dsc files in folders MdePkg or Nt32Pkg, don't know, I'm lost.  I would appreciate a step by step guide or any useful information, thank you.

@@@

Sorry for unclear question. Let me use this question as example:
[Run a UEFI shell command from inside UEFI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738862/run-a-uefi-shell-command-from-inside-uefi-application) and @Yaniv Levinsky answer. 
I want to do similar thing, but when I'm trying to include `C:\MyWorkspace\ShellPkg\Include\Library\ShellLib.h` i get errors like this:

```
1>Building ... c:\myworkspace\MdeModulePkg\Library\CustomizedDisplayLib\CustomizedDisplayLib.inf [IA32]
1>C:\MyWorkspace\ShellPkg\Include\Library\ShellLib.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Protocol/EfiShellInterface.h': No such file or directory
1>NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
```

If I try the first method:

```
EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
BootCheckDriverEntryPoint (
  IN EFI_HANDLE        ImageHandle,
  IN EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE  *SystemTable
  )
{
    EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL    *EfiShellProtocol;
    EFI_STATUS            Status;

    Status = gBS->LocateProtocol(&gEfiShellProtocolGuid,NULL,(VOID **)&EfiShellProtocol);

  //
  // Install UEFI Driver Model protocol(s).
  //

  Status = EfiLibInstallDriverBindingComponentName2 (
             ImageHandle,
             SystemTable,
             &gBootCheckDriverBinding,
             ImageHandle,
             &gBootCheckComponentName,
             &gBootCheckComponentName2
             );
  ASSERT_EFI_ERROR (Status);

  return Status;
}
```

I get.. linker errors I suppose. I also tried to include some libraries in property pages, but I'm not very familiar with Makefile project, I could have done something wrong.

```
1>Building ... c:\myworkspace\MdeModulePkg\Library\FileExplorerLib\FileExplorerLib.inf [IA32]
1>c:\myworkspace\source\BootCheck.c(111): error C2065: 'EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL': undeclared identifier
1>c:\myworkspace\source\BootCheck.c(111): error C2065: 'EfiShellProtocol': undeclared identifier
1>c:\myworkspace\source\BootCheck.c(111): warning C4552: '*': result of expression not used
1>c:\myworkspace\source\BootCheck.c(114): error C2065: 'EfiShellProtocol': undeclared identifier
```

Comment: This question is not currently well suited to stackoverflow, since something like 4 independent answers would be required to resolve it. I would suggest either rewinding to basics and ask about booting an operating system from shell, or moving to some other help forum such as edk2-devel@lists.01.org ([subscription required](https://lists.01.org/mailman/listinfo/edk2-devel)) or #edk2 on freenode (IRC).

Comment: I really don’t understand your question, but I can tell you one thing that should help: it is possible to boot from the shell, simply by running a boot loader from the shell (or from a shell script, or from startup.nsh).

Comment: @prl I edited the main post, with some more information and what I want to achieve.

Comment: @unixsmurf Thanks for the tips, I also added more info, maybe you could help me somehow.

Comment: @ironwing: no, this question is not salvagable. A stackoverflow question is supposed to ask a specific thing - this is asking several layers down of where your problem starts. If you create a new question asking one thing, what I suggested in my first comment, I will try to answer that.